# ArgumentError: binary.split/3 in authentication with phoenix

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using [addict](https://github.com/trenpixster/addict/) with `phoenix` for user authentication. I have created a login page, which takes email and password as input, and using following ajax call, makes `POST` call to `/login` API provided by addict.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-login').click(function() {
      var email = $('#lg_email').val();
      var password = $('#lg_password').val();

      $.post('/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        alert(data.responseText.toSource());
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
      })
    });
  });
```

I am getting following error when I am hitting it's `POST /login` controller from the app:

```
[error] #PID<0.300.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /login
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        (stdlib) binary.erl:242: :binary.split/3
        lib/comeonin/pbkdf2.ex:66: Comeonin.Pbkdf2.checkpw/2
        lib/addict/interactors/addict_manager_interactor.ex:161: Addict.ManagerInteractor.verify_password/4
        lib/addict/controller.ex:95: Addict.Controller.login/2
        lib/addict/controller.ex:89: Addict.Controller.action/2
        lib/addict/controller.ex:89: Addict.Controller.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (my_app) lib/phoenix/router.ex:255: MyApp.Router.dispatch/2
        (my_app) web/router.ex:1: MyApp.Router.do_call/2
        (my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (my_app) lib/plug/debugger.ex:90: MyApp.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (my_app) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: MyApp.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Please help.

Parameters being set to login route are:

```
email: xyz.saurabh@gmail.com
password: asd
```

My mix.lock file is:

```
%{"addict": {:hex, :addict, "0.0.5"},
  "comeonin": {:hex, :comeonin, "0.11.3"},
  "cowboy": {:hex, :cowboy, "1.0.3"},
  "cowlib": {:hex, :cowlib, "1.0.1"},
  "decimal": {:hex, :decimal, "1.1.0"},
  "ecto": {:hex, :ecto, "1.0.4"},
  "fs": {:hex, :fs, "0.9.2"},
  "mailgun": {:hex, :mailgun, "0.0.2"},
  "phoenix": {:hex, :phoenix, "1.0.3"},
  "phoenix_ecto": {:hex, :phoenix_ecto, "1.2.0"},
  "phoenix_html": {:hex, :phoenix_html, "2.2.0"},
  "phoenix_live_reload": {:hex, :phoenix_live_reload, "1.0.1"},
  "plug": {:hex, :plug, "1.0.2"},
  "poison": {:hex, :poison, "1.5.0"},
  "poolboy": {:hex, :poolboy, "1.5.1"},
  "postgrex": {:hex, :postgrex, "0.9.1"},
  "ranch": {:hex, :ranch, "1.1.0"}}
```

Comment: Could you show the parameters that are being submitted to your login route and the arguments being passed to `checkpw`.

Comment: Updated the parameters, How do I print from the deps code?

Comment: Could you please post your controller action too?

Comment: @Gazler: Thanks for feedback, Updated.

Comment: It looks as if the issue is here: [_, _, rounds, salt, hash] = String.split(hash, "$") (in the Comeonin sourcecode). Since there's not a call to :binary.split/3 perhaps you want to check the version of ComeOnIn that Addict requires. Or add the versions of both libraries to your question.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: Updated my `deps` versions in the question, tried to upgrade version of `comeonin` from the `addict` in `deps`, but it didn't update and also tried to update version of `addict`, but stuck in dependencies issues: `Unchecked dependencies for environment dev:
* addict (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 0.1.0", got "0.0.5"
** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies`

Comment: I think that's the issue you need to resolve.

Comment: @Gazier could you take a look at my answer below and correct me if I've gotten the details wrong?  I am relying on memory because I don't have my Elixir dev box handy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so since the issue seems to be the version of addict and comeonin, I'd suggest you try this:

```
mix deps.unlock addict
mix deps.unlock comeonin

#Not sure if you need to specify package name on mix deps.clean or not 
#I am not in a position to double check this right now. That is, you may just want
#to type mix deps.clean

mix deps.clean addict
mix deps.clean comeonin

mix deps.update addict
mix deps.update comeonin
```

**NB: I cannot test this sequence of steps to insure they work correctly so back everything up before you try this.**

I think that sequence of steps will bring addict and comeonin up to the latest versions and that may fix the error you're seeing.